# How to find a text in a web page after loading with python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, pythonanywhere

I wanna find a word in a page and get its url when it uploads in page.but my page loads late. I use beautiful soup but it doesn’t work because my word is in a table and it loads late and i get nothing. I don’t want to use selenium because i want run my code in pythonanywhere and run it evry 30 seconds and send my results by telegram . The page addresses is codal.ir

Comment: Hi there and Welcome to Stack Overflow, maybe you can give a reshape to your question. For reproductibility, could you provide the data(values of variables) and what you expect for output? Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: don't think there is a good way to do it without selenium or equivalent. you can however run selenium from PythonAnywhere. see https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/